select posts from sql except posts from specific category
I have a a query to get post ids of a category
// get ids of posts that belongs to category with id=202
<?php
$args = array( 'showposts' => -1, 'category' => 202, 'post_type' => 'post');
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <?php global $idss; $idss .= "'" .$post->ID . "'" . ","; ?>
<?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

and then I have a select posts from mysql except ids taken in previous query :
// select posts from mysql table and except ids taken in previous code
<?php
function NotSoPop (){
 global $wpdb;
 $tops = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_popularpostsdata, wp_posts WHERE wp_popularpostsdata.postid = $wpdb->posts.ID AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post' AND ID NOT IN ($ids) ORDER BY pageviews ASC limit 12");
 foreach ( $tops as $top ) {
 $return .= '<div class="quick_link_item col-md-6 col-lg-4"><a href="'.get_permalink($top->postid).'">' . get_the_title($top->postid) .''. $top->pageviews.'</a></div>';
 }
 return $return;
}
add_shortcode ("notpop", "NotSoPop");
echo do_shortcode('[notpop]');
?>

I add $ids in NOT IN but its not working.
when I change $ids with static numbers like '10119','10050',... its worked.
where is my mistake?

The variable in the first function is $idss, the one in the second function is called $ids. Also, you need "global $ids" to access the variable in the second function

have you checked the error logs for PHP/MySQL? It looks like you might have a trailing comma but this isn't how SQL queries should be constructed in WordPress. It would be much easier for your global variable to be an array instead of a string of partially assembled SQL fragmetns, then you could use implode to generate the string safely, but you also shouldn't be inserting unprotected variables directly into raw SQL, this is what $wpdb->prepare( is for. You've also misspelt the variable and forgotten to redeclare it as a global, though I'd avoid using globals where possible

all above plus your $idss ends with comma , you need to remove last comma or you'll get an sql error
